# Найти самое повторяющееся слово в строке

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Подскажите, как найти самое повторяющееся слово в строке, не используя регулярные выражения. Используя только массив. Словом считается слово состоящее из букв алфавита, без цифр и спецсимволов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно предварительно отсортировать массив и просто пройтись по нему в цикле:

```
String[] m = "abc abcde abcdef words abc abc g".split(" ");
Arrays.sort(m);

String maxWord = "", word = "";
int maxCount = 0, count = 1;

for (String s : m) {
    if (s.equals(word)) {
        count++;
    } else {
        if (count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count;
            maxWord = word;
        }
        word = s;
        count = 1;
    }
}

if (count > maxCount) {
    maxCount = count;
    maxWord = word;
}

System.out.println("Самое повторяющееся слово: " + maxWord + " (встречается " + maxCount + " раз)");
```

Comment: Alex Chermenin, спасибо за Ваш ответ. Теперь буду разбираться с этой магией ))

Comment: Ничего магического: 1) сортируем массив для того, чтобы одинаковые слова шли друг за другом 2) проходим и смотрим на каждое слово - если оно такое же, как предыдущее - увеличиваем счетчик, если нет - то проверяем, подходит ли оно под самое повторяющееся и сбрасываем счетчик.

Comment: Для чего сортировать массив? От того, с какого слова начать считать количество, алгоритм не изменится, а сортировка лишь время займёт.

Comment: @L'Esperanza просто в этом случае нам не требуется создавать дополнительные коллекции

Comment: Согласен. Но всё же сортировка лишняя.. действительно. (Если посмотрите мой второй вариант, может заметите небольшую разницу). Хотя и не суть важно. Если YuriiS, вы в Java новичок.

Comment: L'Esperanza, абсолютный новичок. Только начал изучать.

Comment: @L'Esperanza либо сортировка и один проход, либо n^2 проходов... нужно подумать, что будет проще.

Comment: Alex Chermenin, почему, в Вашем варианте, без  сортировки число повторений слова не такое (меньше на один), как после сортировки ?

Comment: Потому что учитываются только повторяющиеся _подряд_. Без сортировки подряд нам встречается `abc` дважды, а после сортировки - трижды.

Comment: @AlexChermenin, изменил свой вариант.

Comment: @nick, сортировка-то лишняя, но твой вариант ещё хуже.

Answer (score 3):

Вот хороший вариант:

```
String[] m = "abc abcde abcdef words abc abc g".split(" ");
HashMap<String, Integer> h = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    if (h.containsKey(m[i])) {
        h.replace(m[i], h.get(m[i]) + 1);
    } else {
        h.put(m[i], 1);
    }
}
String s = null;
int p = 0;
for (String w : h.keySet()) {
    if (p < h.get(w)) {
        p = h.get(w);
        s = w;
    }
}
System.out.println("Самое повторяющееся слово: " + w + " (встречается " + h.get(w) + " раз)");
```

Есть, конечно, и такой (без коллекций):

```
String[] m = "abc abcde abcdef words abc abc g".split(" ");
int k[] = new int[]{-1, 0};
for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    if (!m[k[1]].equals(m[i]) || k[0] < 0) {
        int c = 1;
        for (int p = i + 1; p < m.length; p++) {
            if (m[i].equals(m[p])) {
                c++;
            }
        }
        if (k[0] < c) {
            k[0] = c;
            k[1] = i;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("Самое повторяющееся слово: " + m[k[1]] + " (встречается " + k[0] + " раз)");
```

Comment: L'Esperanza, спасибо за Ваш ответ. А как сделать, чтобы метод возвращал самое повторяющееся слово ?

Comment: L'Esperanza, для того чтобы найти самое часто повторяемое слово всегда надо создавать дополнительные массивы ?

Comment: @YuriiS, изменил ответ. Добавил вариант (второй по счёту - новый).

Answer (score 3):

Используя стримы можно еще вот так

```
String str = "This is a test word string to find the most frequent word using stream in Java";
Stream<String> wordsStream = Arrays.stream(str.split(" "));

Map<String, Long> wordCount = wordsStream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
String mostFrequentWord = Collections.max(wordCount.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();
System.out.println("The most frequent word is: " + mostFrequentWord);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно ещё с помощью StreamAPI из Java 8.

```
String input = "kjdf j df iue iue fdj j j";
String word = Arrays.stream(input.split(" "))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .orElse(null);
System.out.println("Most popular word is " + word);
```